# How to Save and Retrieve Boolean Flags from Shared Preferences

Tags: android

How to Save and Retrieve boolean flags in Shared Preference. I tried below thing but doesn't seem to be working

Save :

```
SharedPreferences prefs = activity.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_EULA, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
Boolean lock = prefs.edit().putBoolean("locked", true).commit();
```

Retrieve :

```
SharedPreferences prefes = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
Boolean yourLocked = prefes.getBoolean("locked", false);
```

should get "true" here as i am passing "true" while saving

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting two different instances of `SharedPreferences`.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putBoolean("locked", true);
editor.commit();
```

then

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean value = sharedPref.getBoolean("locked", false);
```

Comment: Should it matter? as far as the "locked" key is same...Also when we are retrieving in some other class obviously the instance will change

Comment: Yes, it matters. That's why you can pass `String` as first parameter, which will be filename for `getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode)`. Check code which I provided. It will work, because instance will be the same.

Comment: It says getActivity() cannot be resolved. I tried getApplicationContext() as well. What is other option.

Comment: Where do you call it? If in custom class, you need to pass `Context` as parameter in contructor.